# LLVM Backend: how to use zero-overhead loop / repeat instructions?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

PIC24 devices have a 'REPEAT' instruction that repeats the following instruction (restrictions apply) for a numer of times (register or literal):

```
REPEAT #16
MOV W0, [W1++]
```

writes the same value from W0 to 16 consecutive words. Could also be used to vector sum, calculating checksums etc. There are also 'DO' instructions for larger loops.

Using these instructions saves both cycles and program space, but optimization seems non-trivial to me: only *after* instruction selection it turns out that the loop body needs only one instruction and thus REPEAT can be used.

Do any existing backends support similar instructions? Where in the code could I start looking?